# Set state the value of variable in a function that returns function which doesn't have stateful widget

Tags: flutter

I'm working on e-commerce project which show several products. So i had to make separate class that has the main components of the product to call it several time inside a list builder.
The image below shows that the user can press on + or - button to change the value of the inside text but this doesn't set state of the text value because this separate class doesn't extend stateful widget.
So my question is, how to set state the value of the text on the screen?

[image]

Edit: this is the code which shows the function. I need to change the value of the inside text when i press on the buttons

```
Widget productCard(String img_link, String title, String details, String price) {
```

int quantityOrdered = 0;
return Container(

```
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
     Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[

        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          child: Image( image: NetworkImage(img_link, ),
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
          ),
        ),
        Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, bottom: 5),child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, bottom: 5),
                  width:150,
                  child: Text(details, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18), softWrap: true, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,)
              ),
              Container(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, bottom: 5),child: Text(price+"\$", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red)))
            ]
        )
      ],
    ),
    // + / - Button
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      width: 250,
      height: 35,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("-", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only( bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),topLeft: Radius.circular(10) )),
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(45,182,169, 1),
                elevation: 1,
                onPressed: (){
                  quantityOrdered--;
                },
              )
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(45,182,169, 0.85),
                height: double.infinity,
                width: 50,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "0",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,

                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("+", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only( bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),topRight: Radius.circular(10) )),
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(45,182,169, 1),
                elevation: 1,
                onPressed: (){
                  quantityOrdered++;
                },
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    // Order Button
    Container(
      width: 150,
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Add to cart", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white),),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only( bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(45,182,169, 1),
        onPressed: (){},
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

);
}

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, you press a button in the UI and want a variable in a separate class to update. I recommend checking out various state management techniques.

The easiest for your case in my opinion would be using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Alternatively, you could call `ClassName.variableName = xyz` from your UI, although, in that case I recommend using a setter or method to set that for you (so you can keep your instance variables private).

PS I'm a Flutter noob myself, so I could be way offbase :) Good luck!

UPDATE =>

Here is an example where I have UI that returns a widget tree through a method from a completely separate class called `myWidget()`. Inside the widgets that are returned there is a `FlatButton` that has an `onPressed`, this is used to update the value variable in the class (`value++;`). It also calls `reload()` which is something I passed it from the UI. This reload method calls `setState` in the UI after the class has variable (`value`) has been updated. This calls a UI rebuild which then forces it to take the new value from the class. I tried it and pressing the button updates the text on the button (`value`) every time you press it. Here is the code:

UI:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'logic.dart';

class Stack2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Stack2State createState() => _Stack2State();
}

class _Stack2State extends State<Stack2> {
  Logic myLogic = Logic();

  void reload() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      body: myLogic.myWidget(reload),
    );
  }
}
```

Logic Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Logic {
  int value = 0;

  Center myWidget(Function reload) {
    return Center(
      child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            value++;
            reload();
          },
          child: Text(value.toString())),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Sorry but that wasn't what i meant. I shared the code. It is a function that returns the card of the product but the user needs to press on + or - buttons to change the ordered quantity. I need this to be updated on the screen. How can I do this on a function that does not extend stateful widget?

Comment: @MU'menAhmed I've edited my answer to show you a simple example of what I think you are trying to achieve. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks! It worked. So sending a function including only setState method does it.